# Problems with Shiny, arguments must be of same length

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have, once again, run into some problems with Shiny. When I run my app I get the following message:

Warning: Error in tapply: arguments must have same length
[No stack trace available]

Still quite new to R, I dont understand why I get this warning. I've been randomly experiement with aes_string instead of aes in the graph, but I can't find any workable solution. I would be so grateful if someone could help me.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
df_bransch <- data_frame(
        kommun = c("Bjuv", "Bjuv", "Bjuv", "Bromölla", "Bromölla", "Bromölla", "Båstad", "Båstad", "Båstad", "Helsingborg", "Helsingborg", "Helsingborg"),
        bransch = c("Besöksnäring", "Byggnadsmaterial", "Fastigheter", "Besöksnäring", "Byggnadsmaterial", "Fastigheter", 
                    "Besöksnäring", "Byggnadsmaterial", "Fastigheter", "Besöksnäring", "Byggnadsmaterial", "Fastigheter"),
        Anställda = c(46, 369, 36, 57, 40, 36, 525, 5, 1133, 2392, 195, 1042),
        Förädlingsvärde = c(20724, 579892, 91406, 26097, 136440, 51731, 252891, 3852, 1343391, 1257333, 176595, 5017640))

ui <- fluidPage(
        navbarPage(title = "TEST", id = "nav",
                   tabPanel("Branschstruktur",
                            sidebarLayout(
                                    sidebarPanel(selectInput("kom", "Kommun", choices = unique(df_bransch$kommun), selected = "Malmö"),
                                                 varSelectInput("var", "Variabel", df_bransch[c(3,4)])),
                                    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))),
                   tabPanel("Utveckling"))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
        
        df <- reactive({df_bransch %>%
                        req(input$var, input$kom) %>% 
                filter(kommun == input$kom)
        })
        
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
                ggplot(df(), aes(x = reorder(bransch, input$var), y = input$var)) +
                        geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
                        labs(title = paste0("Branschstruktur, ", input$kom, " år 2018"),
                             subtitle = paste0("Variabel: ", input$var),
                             caption = "Källa: Bisnode") +
                        coord_flip()
        })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make the following change:

```
ggplot(df(), aes(x = reorder(bransch, df()[[input$var]]), y = df()[[input$var]]))
```

Also, add to `labs()` the code `y = "Bransch", x = as.name(input$var),` to give proper labels on x and y axis. Then you will get the output as:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, but why isen't it enough to call df() at ggplot(df(), aes(..?

Comment: `input$var` requires Non-Standard Evaluation.  Hence the call is `df()[[input$var]]`.  If you are using existing names within the dataset, you can give the name of the variable, and `ggplot` will pick it up from `df()`. You can replace `df()[[input$var]]` with `!!input$var`.  You will get the same result.

Comment: You just needed `!!` in front of `input$var` in `aes`.